# Can I enter the side of the panel *through* the stud?

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a service panel that is the usual setup, mounted between two studs. The studs are not load bearing.  I want to bring NM (Romex) cable into the side of the panel, but that involves drilling through the studs.  **How do I protect the cable?**

Would this work, using a rigid conduit nipple then clamped by conduit nuts? (I might have to add washers or shim on the outside in case I can't get the threading just right).

[image]

Comment: Why are you thinking that the wiring needs more protection than it would in a common stud penetration?

Comment: your drawing is unclear .... change the color of the panel wall to red and insert an explanation into your question

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I do believe fiber or insulated bushings and at least some form of strain relief would be a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there's nothing saying you can't put strain relief clamps facing the inside of the panel. I'd simply drill slightly oversized holes through the studs, centered on the knockout, to allow installation of the clamp. Say 1-1/4" for a 3/8" clamp, then run wiring as per usual.

You could also use snap-in, self-clamping bushings that require no screw tightening and insert them from through the stud *or* from inside the panel.

Since the wiring is centered on the stud, as it would be anywhere else in the house, no protection would be necessary.